# Text Classification Technique for this scenario

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am completely new to Machine Learning algorithms and I have a quick question with respect to Classification of a dataset.

Currently there is a training data that consists of two columns Message and Identifier.

Message - Typical message extracted from Log containing timestamp and some text
Identifier - Should classify the category based on the message content.

The training data was prepared by extracting a particular category from the tool and labelling it accordingly.

Now the test data contains just the message and I am trying to obtain the Category accordingly.

Which approach is most helpful in this scenario ? Is it the Supervised or Unsupervised Learning ?

I have a trained dataset and I am trying to predict the Category for the Test Data.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your labels are exact then you can classify using ANN, SVM etc. But labels are not exact you have to cluster data with respect to the features you have in data. K-means or nearest neighbour can be the starting point for clustering.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Geek !! As per my understanding since this is an unsupervised learning, K means or Nearest Neighbor are the suggested ones over supervised learning right ??

Comment: No. A) you are supervised, not unsupervised, B) kmeans is unsupervised, kNN is supervised, you are mixing up things, and C) neither is a promising candidate, they tend to perform rather poor.

Answer (score 0):

You have labels to predict, and training data.

So by definition it is a supervised problem.

Try any classifier for text, such as NB, kNN, SVM, ANN, RF, ...

It's hard to predict which will work best on your data. You willhave to **try and evaluate several**.

Answer (score 0):

It is supervised learning, and a classification problem.

However, obviously  you do not have the label column (the to-be-predicted value) for your testset. Thus, you cannot calculate error measures (such as False Positive Rate, Accuracy etc) for that test set.

You could, however, split the set of labeled training data that you **do** have into a smaller training set and a validation set. Split it 70%/30%, perhaps. Then build a prediction model from your smaller 70% training dataset. Then  tune it on your 30% validation set. When accuracy is good enough, then  apply it on your testset to obtain/predict the missing values.

Which techniques / algorithms to use is a different question. You do not give enough information to answer that. And even if you did you still need to tune the model yourself.